# How, briefly, did Mockito implement its fluent syntax for stubbing?

Tags: java, mockito, fluent

I'm in a situation now where I need to implement something similar to  Mockito's fluent syntax:

```
when( mock.arbitraryMethod( arg1, matcher2 ) ).thenReturn( foo );
```

I spent about 10 minutes looking over the source at github without seeing the basic pattern that achieves what amounts to *quoting* the arbitrary method.  Somehow the mock object has to record what method was called, and the arguments passed to it, in some buffer which `when()` can subsequently obtain (it can't "see" the mock or the method, which will be eagerly evaluated beforehand); and the problem compounds when you pass a matcher to that method instead of a regular argument.

Can someone sum up the trick?

Comment: I seem to remember mocks having unique identifiers. Calling method on mock records that identifier, method name and args to a ThreadLocal, that then is used in calling `when()` to construct an invokation expectation. After `thenReturn` call the expectation is saved in another thread local.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little code helps illustrate what is happening, with some surprising results.  The way you are expected to use Mockito (and the way you *should* use Mockito) normally look something like this:

```
    @Test
    public void whenClauseExplanation_v1() {
        MyImpl myMock = mock(MyImpl.class);

        when(myMock.getStringObj()).thenReturn("What In The World?");

        assertThat(myMock.getStringObj()).isEqualToIgnoringCase("WHAT IN THE WORLD?");
    }
```

However, you can take apart the way it is actually invoked and see some surprising results:

```
    @Test
    public void whenClauseExplanation_v2() {
        // 1. The argument to when() is a method call on the mock object, the method being stubbed.
        // 2. Argument gets evaluated before when() is invoked
        // 3. Eval of method call on mock records the invocation and arguments in ThreadLocal storage
        // 4. "when()" is invoked, pops the most recent recorded invocation
        // 5. ".thenReturn()" stubs the method to return a specific value when a matching invocation is encountered

        // To demonstrate this:

        MyImpl myMock = mock(MyImpl.class);

        myMock.getStringObj(); // primes the pump
        when(null).thenReturn("What In The World?");  // Huh? passing null?

        // The argument itself doesn't really matter!  But ordinary usage ensures the invocation is recorded before "when()" is evaluated.
        assertThat(myMock.getStringObj()).isEqualToIgnoringCase("WHAT IN THE WORLD?");
    }
```

As you can see, the argument to `when()` doesn't even matter, except to provide type-safety for the expected return type that may be provided in the argument to `thenReturn()`

Comment: Is there protection against multiple mock invocations inside the call to `when()`, as in `when( mock.doSomething( mock.doAnother() ) )` ?

Comment: The answer is no.  A `when()` call only looks at the most recently executed method call on an uninitialized mock.  But in your example above `doAnother()` executes first, followed by `doSomething()`, making `doSomething()` the most recently executed method on the mock before `when` is executed.  But it gets a little more complex than that since you just made `doSomething()` parameterized.  And we would need to now whether you programmed `mock.doAnother()` already before this statement.

Answer (score 2):

First of all your example is wrong.

It should look like this:

```
when( mock.arbitraryMethod( eq(arg1), matcher2.match() ) ).thenReturn( foo );
```

now let's see how it works.

1. `eq(arg1)` and `matcher2.match()` are invoked. Invocation of both of this method are stored in some static variable (like invocation history list).
2. `mock.arbitraryMethod(...)`  is invoked. It is method of mock so `Mockito` intercept it and store its invocation in history.
3. `when(...)` is invoked. Here all the magic is brewed. It check the history and store it in object that it returns (then clear history).
4. `thenReturn` just configure mock how to behave.

It leads us to a few rules that restrict `Mockito` usage, like:

1. You can not mix values and `eq(...)` like things in invocation because it do not allow to find out sequence of arguments.
2. To mock method that throw exception you need to use other syntax like `doReturn(x).when(...)`
3. Some other stuff.

Comment: Sorry, did you mean "you *can't* mix values and [matchers]"?

Comment: The main question I have is in your points 2 and 3.  Is the history global per thread, as @M. Prokhorov claims?

Comment: @JudgeMental You can't write `when( mock.method( eq(arg1),value) ).thenReturn( foo )`

Comment: @JudgeMental I don't have those knowledge, but suppose it is per thread because test can bu runned in parallel.

Comment: when `when` is invoked its parameter is `null` (the default return from any method on a mock). How does `when` know what mock was used to provide its argument?

Comment: At second point all required information are stored. Actual passed value is ignored.